# Problemas con validacion isset _GET

Tags: php, html

Tengo un problema con mi código que es el siguiente. Mediante _GET obtengo un valor id que el mismo es el nombre de un proyecto. Entonces agrego lo siguiente:
//obtener el ID de la URL

```
if(isset($_GET['id_proyecto'])){
    $id_proyecto = $_GET['id_proyecto'];
};
```

Según entendí el isset valida que ese dato exista. Cuando obtiene esa información lo guarda en la variable id_proyecto que luego la utilizo para buscar en la BD el nombre del proyecto.
Este es el error que me aparece si no hay un Id en la url
[image: Error]

Pero si selecciono un proyecto, desaparece ese mensaje y muestra el nombre del proyecto. Si funcionara bien debería mostrar un mensaje que dice Seleccione un proyecto a la izquierda.

agradezco su ayuda. Saludos

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 22? Pon el código completo para ver el contexto. El error no ocurre en las tres líneas que has puesto en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema no está en ese fragmento de código en concreto sino más bien a que usas la variable `$id_proyecto` posteriormente y, como no se ha seteado, da el error.

Prueba a cambiar el fragmento de código mostrado por:

```
$id_proyecto = isset($_GET['id_proyecto']) ? $_GET['id_proyecto'] : '';
```

O bien por este, más equivalente con respecto a tú código si te es más comprensible que con operadores ternarios:

```
$id_proyecto = '';
if(isset($_GET['id_proyecto'])){
    $id_proyecto = $_GET['id_proyecto'];
};
```

De este modo, siempre se define la variable `$id_proyecto` (puedes cambiar el string vacío '' por cualquier otro si te viene mejor).

Comment: Hola Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo necesario en responder mi pregunta. Utilice la segunda opción que das y funciona muy bien. Muchas gracias. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de hacer un `isset()` puedes hacer la siguiente asignación:

```php
$idProyecto = $_GET['id_proyecto'] ?? null;
```

Así si llega el ID del proyecto se asignará y el ámbito de la variable `$idProyecto` será el correcto para que líneas de más abajo puedan acceder a ella.

Comment: Vale la pena mencionar que el [operador ??](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) se encuentra disponible a partir de `PHP 7.0 o superior`

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta, también utilice tu sugerencia y funciono perfecto. Muchas gracias por tu aporte y tu tiempo. Saludos